# how to compile golang project with docker volume and download private module from bitbucket?

Tags: docker, go

how to compile golang project with docker container? I want to compile and retrieve the project build, using docker cli

sample docker command

```
docker run -v $(pwd)/:/app -w /app -v $SSH_AUTH_SOCK:/tmp/ssh_auth.sock  -e SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh_auth.sock  --name golanguser golang:1.17 sh -c "export GOPRIVATE=https://user:pass@bitbucket.org/repo/ && go build -o main bitbucket.org/repo/source"
```

Comment: `go build` creates an executable for your project, it doesn't run your code. Either call your executable after you built it, or `go run`.

Note this doesn't create an optimized build. The best solution would be to have a Dockerfile directly in your repository, and build it from here (instead of fetching your code from bitbucket in the docker image).

Answer (score 0):

Building a go project is usually done in a [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/language/golang/build-images/#multi-stage-builds)

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

##
## Build
##
FROM golang:1.16-buster AS build

WORKDIR /app

COPY go.mod ./
COPY go.sum ./
RUN go mod download

COPY *.go ./

RUN go build -o /docker-gs-ping

##
## Deploy
##
FROM gcr.io/distroless/base-debian10

WORKDIR /

COPY --from=build /docker-gs-ping /docker-gs-ping

EXPOSE 8080

USER nonroot:nonroot

ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-gs-ping"]
```

With:

```
docker build -t docker-gs-ping:multistage -f Dockerfile.multistage .
```

That way, you can deploy the built application in the image of your choice, resulting in a markedly *smaller* image size to run.